# Should I use custom HTTP methods for maintenance?

Tags: http, rest, http-method

Currently I'm working on a CMS containing on a RESTful webservice. For the regular REST actions, I use the default HTTP methods GET, PUT, POST and DELETE. However, I'm thinking of adding a custom method MAINTENANCE, which I can use for maintenance purposes, like integrity checks, re-indexing, etc. These kind of maintenance can only be invoked by administrators of the CMS.

My webservice supports overriding the HTTP method by defining the url parameter _method. This way I can 'post' a form, setting the _method to PUT. I can also use this same parameter to set the method to MAINTENANCE. Technically it is fairly easy to implement a custom HTTP method.

My questions is more <strike>ethical</strike> about proper design. On one hand, custom HTTP methods are allowed and technically not difficult to implement. On the other hand, some people advice not to use custom HTTP methods.

Should I use custom HTTP methods for maintenance tasks? Or are there other best practices?

Comment: This is a design issue, not an ethics issue!

Comment: I'm not clear on what your maintenance use cases are. Are they per-resource? Why not just have a resource modelling maintenance resources, and do the normal GET/PUT etc on those?

Comment: You're right, it's not about ethics, but about good or bad design.

Comment: A use case is that I have a search index. Sometimes I want to re-index all documents. But I expect I want to do some data-integrity checks in the future too. Or some aggregation tasks. I want to have a per-resource maintenance, as well as a main maintenance (basically calling all per-resource maintenances).

Comment: I think I'd have a /maintenance/check, maintenance/index sub resource  - that lets you index everything (/maintenance/index at the top level) or a  specific set of resources ...whatever-resource/maintenance/index?  You might issues with proxies/app. firewalls, and debugging tools wouldn't know about them, etc

Comment: You may want to read http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-26#section-8.1.2

Comment: @Paul, I'll use your suggestion with the /maintenance/ route. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integrity checks and re-indexing are not resource actions that you want to expose to a user. These can be achieved via a different servlet that's non_REST.

Adding more methods to HTTP is not a normal practice. You can look some to the REST interfaces that are public.